# function of two variables reduced to 1 variable but issues with minimizing in Python

Tags: python, optimization, scipy

I have a function which is multivariate (code below), depending on `x1` and `x2` and I have a target output value in mind for this function, named `target`. I fix `x1` and provide my `target` in the outer function: `find_x2`. The objective is to minimize the inner function `error`, which is just the squared distance between my output target and the resulting value `est`, with respect to `x2`.

But having run it:

`find_x2(target = .12, x1 = 100)` yields `x2 = 0.99899`, but it should be roughly `.80`.

It appears the function is minimizing with respect to `est` instead of `x2`, but I can't see why. Any help would be appreciated.

Code:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import minimize_scalar, minimize 

def find_x2(x1, target): 
    def error(x2, x1 = x1, target = target):
        k = np.zeros(x1) 
        V = np.zeros(x1) 
        for i in range(x1): 
            try:
                k[i-1] = (i/x1)**(-1/x2)
            except: 
                k[x1-1]=1
        for i in range(x1): 
            V[i] = k[i]/sum(k)
        est = sum(V**2) 
        return (target - est)**2
    return minimize_scalar(error, bounds = (.001,.999), method = 'bounded')
```

Comment: Should the first argument to minimize_scalar be ```error```?  Looks like you're minimizing some other function

Comment: Thank you, it should be `error` thank you for that. I will edit the question to prevent further confusion.

Comment: Could you provide a reasonable triple (x1, x2, target)?  i'd like to run this

Comment: x1 = 100, target = 0.12 and x2 = 0.8016846

Comment: the try/except doesn't work like you expect -- there are nan's in the last element of each k vector.  Maybe compute as a vector then use numpy.roll to shift the elements afterward

Comment: note ```(i/x1)**(-1/x2)``` can be rewritten as ```(x1/i)**(1/x2)```  (reciprocal + exponent sign flip) -- this removes the craziness at x1 == 0

Comment: Works like a charm, thank you for your help. Laws of exponents hah! I need to stay aware of things like this. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this version:

```
def find_x2(x1, target): 
    def error(x2, x1 = x1, target = target):
        k = np.zeros(x1) 
        V = np.zeros(x1) 
        for i in range(x1): 
            try:
                k[i-1] = (x1/i)**(1/x2)
            except:
                k[x1-1]=1
        for i in range(x1):
            V[i] = k[i]/sum(k)
        est = sum(V**2)
        return (target - est)**2
    return minimize_scalar(error, bounds = (.001,.999), method = 'bounded')
```

```
find_x2(100, 0.12)
```

prints

```
    fun: 9.668753433849857e-14
 message: 'Solution found.'
    nfev: 14
  status: 0
 success: True
       x: 0.801701074855243
```